# What is command to edit markup in Geocortex?

Tags: geocortex

"DrawingToolsRegion" in a Geocortex Essentials 2.5 toolbar provides too many options for editing markup/drawings.  It is possible to construct a set of custom buttons that use the underlaying commands of the region -- AddMarkup, ClearMarkup, etc.  However the documentation has no information about a command to edit markup.

Is anyone familiar with the command I am looking for?

Or alternatively, is there an easy way to remove most of the markup shapes from the DrawingToolsRegion?

I am just trying to allow for rectangles and polygons to be used.  This is for Silverlight Viewer 2.5.

[image: The "Edit" tool of DrawingToolsRegion is circled]

Answer (score 1):

The solution is just to move to using the HTML5 viewer.  Not sure why this was unavailable in silverlight, but it was easy to find in HTML5 viewer.